# why does wsl2 wslconfig file not working?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v, hypervisor

I'm running version 20H2 (OS Build 19042) on windows home edition, i built a linux kernel and im trying to set it up on my machine by configuring the `.wslconfig` file as follow:

```
[wsl2]
kernel=c:\\wslkernel\\bzImage
```

everything is at place according to the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config

any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out i was running wsl version 1 and not wsl2 - for the full thread on the issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6728